How to monitor module loading and obtain version number
I tried the following code，I am trying to add a custom MetaPathFinder to listen for module loading
import importlib.util
import sys
from importlib.abc import MetaPathFinder


class ModuleLoadListener(MetaPathFinder):
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        for finder in sys.meta_path:
            if finder == self:
                continue
            spec = finder.find_spec(fullname, path, target)
            if spec is not None:
                spec.loader = CustomLoader(spec.loader)
                return spec

        return None


class CustomLoader(importlib.abc.Loader):
    def __init__(self, loader):
        self.loader = loader

    def create_module(self, spec):
        return self.loader.create_module(spec)

    def exec_module(self, module):
        return self.loader.exec_module(module)


sys.meta_path.insert(0, ModuleLoadListener())

import requests

But he had an abnormality，But there are some modules that do not report errors when imported
  File "D:\app\developer\py3\python3.11\Lib\site-packages\requests-2.31.0-py3.11.egg\requests\utils.py", line 63, in <module>
    DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH = certs.where()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\app\developer\py3\python3.11\Lib\site-packages\certifi-2023.11.17-py3.11.egg\certifi\core.py", line 37, in where
    _CACERT_PATH = str(_CACERT_CTX.__enter__())
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\app\developer\py3\python3.11\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\app\developer\py3\python3.11\Lib\importlib\resources\_common.py", line 80, in _tempfile
    os.write(fd, reader())
                 ^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\app\developer\py3\python3.11\Lib\importlib\resources\abc.py", line 76, in read_bytes
    with self.open('rb') as strm:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\app\developer\py3\python3.11\Lib\importlib\resources\_adapters.py", line 141, in open
    raise FileNotFoundError("Can't open orphan path")
FileNotFoundError: Can't open orphan path


Am I doing this right？
